# Adding submenu to a particular menuitem of contextmenu strip

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu

I have a contextmenu strip in which menu items will be populated based on certain condition.

Ex:

for the condition1:

```
myContextMenuStrip.Items.Clear();
myContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Item title", null, myClickHandler);
myContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Item Status", null, myClickHandler);
myContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Item Variables", null, myClickHandler);
```

Condition2:

```
myContextMenuStrip.Items.Clear();
myContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Item Status", null, myClickHandler);
```

For the condition1 to add a submenu to ItemStatus i use

```
(myContextMenuStrip.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Submenu1", null, new EventHandler(gridcontextsubMenu_ItemClicked));
(myContextMenuStrip.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Submenu2", null, new EventHandler(gridcontextsubMenu_ItemClicked));
```

For the condition2 to add a submenu to ItemStatus i use

```
(myContextMenuStrip.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Submenu1", null, new EventHandler(gridcontextsubMenu_ItemClicked));
(myContextMenuStrip.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Submenu2", null, new EventHandler(gridcontextsubMenu_ItemClicked));
```

But i need a general way to add submenu to the menu item ItemStatus.

Kindly share the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Items` property for a `ContextMenuStrip` returns a `ToolStripItemCollection` which allows you to use the indexer with either an index number or name.  So, you can use the item name for `Items`.  For example:

```
(myContextMenuStrip.Items["Item Status"] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Submenu1", null, new EventHandler(gridcontexsubMenu_ItemClicked));
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Trying this now. Hope will get back with positive results